# Ошибка в коде С++ Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int n = 3;
    int arr[n][n];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        i++;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < n)
        {
            j++;
            cout << "arr[" << i << "][" << j << "]=";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "\nYour matrix:\n";
    while (i < n)
    {
        i++;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < n)
        {
            j++;
            cout << setw(3) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nNew matrix: \n";
    while (i < n)
    {
        i++;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < n)
        {
            j++;
            if (arr[i][j] < 0)
            {
                arr[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[i][j] = 1;
            }

            cout << setw(3) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Очевидная проблема - проверки на выход за пределы массивов происходит *до* инкремента индекса элемента массива, а не после:

```
constexpr ::std::size_t const rows_count{3};
constexpr ::std::size_t const cols_count{rows_count};
int arr[rows_count][cols_count]{};
for(::std::size_t row_index{}; row_index < rows_count; ++row_index)
{
    for(::std::size_t col_index{}; col_index < cols_count; ++col_index)
    {
        ::std::cout << "arr[" << row_index << "][" << col_index << "]=";
        ::std::cin >> arr[row_index][col_index];
    }
}
```

Comment: А как сделать именно с while?

Comment: constexpr ::std::size_t const? А для чего константному выражению еще и спецификатор const?

Comment: @Horror С while инкремент надо переносить в конец блока. А так и нулевой элемент пропускается.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Это на самом деле несколько избыточно, однако это имеет смысл для поддержания однообразности кода, позволяет легче искать места, где в явном виде используется `std::size_t const`, а также может быть полезно когда `constexpr` поддерживается только по условию.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто исправил ваши ошибки:

```
constexpr unsigned  n = 3;  
int arr[n][n];
unsigned i = 0, j = 0;
while ( i < n)
{           
    while (j < n)
    {           
        cout << "arr[" << i << "][" << j << "]=";
        cin >> arr[i][j];
        ++j;
    }
    ++i;
    j = 0;
}
cout << "\nYour matrix:\n";
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < n)
{           
    while (j < n)
    {           
        cout << setw(3) << arr[i][j];
        ++j;
    }
    cout << endl;
    ++i;
    j = 0;
}

cout << "\nNew matrix: \n";
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < n)
{           
    while (j < n)
    {           
        if (arr[i][j] < 0)
        {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i][j] = 1;
        }

        cout << setw(3) << arr[i][j];
        ++j;
    }
    cout << endl;
    ++i;
    j = 0;
}
```

каждый раз вы доолжны обходить массив с первого элемента, а для этого каждый раз  индексы должны быть нулевыми...